# Adding javascript to a Django redirect (HttpResponse)

Tags: python, django, redirect, httpresponse

I am using a redirect in Django `from django.shortcuts import redirect`

What I want, is for the user to be displayed a Javascript alert message before being redirected.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
response = redirect("someUrl")
response.write('<script>alert(\'You must remove an item before adding another\');</script>')
response['location'] += "?active=" + "all"
return response
```

The redirect works, but the Javascript does not. I also tried

```
response = HttpResponse('<script>alert(\'You must remove an item before adding another\');</script>')
return response
```

This triggers the alert window, but I'm not sure how to add an equivalent redirect as the method above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `js appproach` `window.location`

```
url = 'someUrl'
resp_body = '<script>alert("You must remove an item before adding another");\
             window.location="%s"</script>' % url
return HttpResponse(resp_body)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting confused between frontend and backend. When this view is requested by the user, the server (via Django's [`HTTPResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/http/response/#HttpResponseRedirect)) is sending a [`302` redirect HTTP response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) that tells the browser to redirect to a different page. This is different to a normal `200` response (i.e. a normal Django response object, not a redirect) within which you could include a javascript alert.

You need to show that javascript on the view you are initially loading *before* the user is returned the redirect response.